Issue with autoresize tinyMCE 6 editor on iPhone
I have an autoresize tinyMCE editor in my site that I start at one line (thus looking like a single line text box) which expands using the tinyMCE autoresize plugin. I am using tinyMCE 6. Just regular mode, not inline, with no toolbar, status bar or anything else. It works perfectly on my Windows machine and also on my iPad, but on my iPhone, it initializes much bigger, like there is some hidden mobile minimum height that is overriding my min height setting. It is around the height that fits 7 lines of text.
Note that if I enter more than would fit, it DOES resize properly, so that is great, but if I then delete, it shrinks but just to the height it started at and doesn't shrink more.
My Init code is as follows:
tinymce.init({
      selector: elementid,
      plugins: 'autoresize',
      menubar: false,
      toolbar: false,
      statusbar: false,
      browser_spellcheck: true,
      promotion: false,
      contextmenu: false,
      autoresize_bottom_margin: 0,
      min_height:25,
      height:25,
      paste_as_text: true,
      newline_behavior: 'linebreak',
      placeholder:placeholder,
      formats: {
        bold : {inline : 'b' },  
        italic : {inline : 'i' },
        underline : {inline : 'u'}
      },
      content_style: `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&family=Oswald&family=PT+Sans+Narrow&display=swap');
      body { `+fontcss+`;line-height: 1.2em; padding:0px !important; margin:3px !important}
      p {margin:0px}
      .mce-content-body[data-mce-placeholder] {
        cursor: text;
      }
      `
    });

Here is a snapshot from the iPhone:
[Editor on iPhone][1]
And here is an image from the desktop, where it is what I want:
[Proper small one-line MCE editor][2]
tiny
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/rURKoSuk.jpg
[2]: https://i.sstatic.net/8C6cDPTK.png
Without a Mac computer to show a debug console, are there any ideas out there for why this would happen?  Something must be different in the tinyMCE code for iPhones and similar mobile devices, but the docs just give me the min_height and height parameters I am already using.

For anyone having this problem, it seems it was inherent to the downloadable tinyMCE from version 6.4 through the latest 7.5, where the size is again what it should be.
